# How to avoid fragment superposition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to display a list, using a ListFragment and a custom adapter. Each row includes a TextView and button. It looks like this :

[image: Normal view]

When a button is clicked, I want the element of the list to change. In order to do this, I want to replace the existing ListFragment with another. My problem is that the second fragment is added over the first one, like this :

[image: Fragment superposition]

Here is the code that is executed when I click on a button, in the custom ArrayAdapter :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                //Some unrelated stuff

                //I want to replace the old ListGeneratedFragment by a new one
                ListGeneratedFragment fragment = new ListGeneratedFragment();
                ((MainActivity)getContext())
                        .getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_list_meals, fragment)
                        .commit();
            }
});
```

I've already used the same technique in other parts of my code, and it works perfectly. I don't understand why the old fragment isn't replaced here.

Comment: Is your first fragment also in the `R.id.main_list_meals` container? How is that first fragment added to the container?

Comment: Yes the first fragment is also in the R.id.main_list_meals container. It is added using getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace(...).commit()
So it is added the same way, but in this case it doesn't work

Comment: So in one case, you're using the Activity's `getSupportFragmentManager()` and the other case you're using a totally different `FragmentManager` in that you're using the `getChildFragmentManager()` of some parent Fragment?